# Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser ( urllib, python 3.6)

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.6

Good Evening ,

i have an error with my urllib code with websites that work with javascript .

this is the error that i get :

"

"This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser".

"

im using python 3.6 with urllib (request), How Can I solve it ?

Comment: Please show some (reduced) code and input that shows the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you are accessing requires javascript and cookies. Urllib only provides support for cookies (with [cookie jar](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/http.cookiejar.html)). To get around the need for javascript, check out a library like selenium, and use it with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

```
pip install selenium
```

Selenium with phantomjs is more powerful then urllib, but you pay the penalty of it being a bit slower. Heres is some simple code to get off the ground with selenium and phantomjs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

For more information on how to do specific things with selenium, check out the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Ok great , how can i write 'request.urlopen("website")' in selenium library

Comment: driver.get("http://website.com")